# Which HWUT files to put under version control

Tags: unit-testing, hwut

I am using HWUT for unit testing and want to put my tests under version control. Adding the test code and the GOOD folder is obvious. But what about other files e.g. the ADM folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NEEDED**

- GOOD/*:
- hwut-info.dat: If you specify it.
- Makefile: If you specifiy it.
- Your test scripts and source files that implement the test.
- ADM/cache.fly: Optional; Only check-in if queries on past tests are to be accomplished without doing the tests.

**NOT TO BE CHECKED-IN**

- OUT/*
- Any result produced by 'make'
- Any temporary log files

*Note, SCMs usually have a 'prop:ignore' property, or an 'ignore' file. You may adapt this according to the information above.*